# Export to CSV with Headers

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I'm trying to export a query form Microsoft Access into `.csv` file.

I need the export to have headers:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "CSV_TEST_SPECIFICATION", "tempQuery", "file.csv", True
```

The code works fine except for the fact that there is no headers in the `file.csv`.

`CSV_TEST_SPECIFICATION` is the same specification used to import the original CSV.

It includes first row as headers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the last argument, set to 'True', should give you your headers.  See the link below for more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext

```
Use True (1) to use the first row of the text file as field names when importing, exporting, or linking. Use False (0) to treat the first row of the text file as normal data. If you leave this argument blank, the default (False) is assumed. This argument is ignored for Microsoft Word mail merge data files, which must always contain the field names in the first row.
```

Try Compact and Repair.  Maybe that will fix it.  I've seen Access do some weird things over the years, and often doing a CR will get everything straightened out.

Comment: Thank you. This is the problem - it doesn't work. I ended up writing code to open .csv file as .txt and adding a new line with headers to all exported files.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. 
Try this:

```
Public Sub Export()

    Dim filepath As String
        filepath = "[A valid path]\FileName.csv"

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "QueryName", filepath, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, skipping specification works, but it makes file too big. The purpose of this macro is to load .csv file that is too big for excel and divide it into smaller parts. If I "divide" it into one part without specification it makes the output file bigger in size than the input (and since its more than excel can take I cannot compare those 2). File size stays the same if I use Specification, but it kips the first row...